# iOS Performance troubles with transparency

Tags: ios, performance, transparency

I just generated a gradient with transparency programmatically by adding a solid color and a gradient to an image mask. I then applied the resulting image to my UIView.layer.content. The visual is fine, but when I scroll object under the transparency, the app gets chunky. Is there a way to speed up?

My minital thought was caching the resulting gradient. Another thought was to create a gradient that is only one pixel wide and stretch it to cover the desired area. Will either of these approaches help the performance?

Joe

Comment: could you post your drawing code it might help

Comment: if you remove the gradient, does scrolling work fine?

Comment: You can see my code and download the class [link](http://codingangry.com/index.php/site/article/ios_gradent_with_transparency)

Comment: Yes if I remove the gradient it works fine. But the design calls for a gradient. I guess PNGs are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I recall reading (though I don't remember where) that core graphics gradients can have a noticeable effect on performance. If you can, using a png for your gradient instead should resolve the issue that you are seeing.